# Why C# TypeBuilder.DefineConstructor always create a Constructor named ".ctor"?

Tags: c#, reflection

I tried this sample. DefineConstructor does not provide a way to set Constructor name.
I wish to define a dynamic type so I can use it in DI container. But I cannot Get it work when I am trying to set a method name of constructor.

```
MethodBuilder myMethodBuilder = null;
AppDomain myCurrentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
// Create assembly in current CurrentDomain.
AssemblyName myAssemblyName = new AssemblyName();
myAssemblyName.Name = "TempAssembly";
// Create a dynamic assembly.
myAssemblyBuilder = myCurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly
         (myAssemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
// Create a dynamic module in the assembly.
myModuleBuilder = myAssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("TempModule");
FieldInfo myFieldInfo =
   myModuleBuilder.DefineUninitializedData("myField", 2, FieldAttributes.Public);
// Create a type in the module.
TypeBuilder myTypeBuilder = myModuleBuilder.DefineType("TempClass",TypeAttributes.Public);
FieldBuilder myGreetingField = myTypeBuilder.DefineField("Greeting",
                                    typeof(String), FieldAttributes.Public);
Type[] myConstructorArgs = { typeof(String) };
// Define a constructor of the dynamic class.
ConstructorBuilder myConstructor = myTypeBuilder.DefineConstructor(
MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.Standard, myConstructorArgs);
// Display the name of the constructor.
Console.WriteLine("The constructor name is  : "+ myConstructor.Name);
// Display the 'Type' object from which this object was obtained.
Console.WriteLine("The reflected type  is  : "+ myConstructor.ReflectedType);
// Display the signature of the field.
Console.WriteLine(myConstructor.Signature);
// Display the constructor builder instance as a string.
Console.WriteLine(myConstructor.ToString());
```

Comment: `.ctor` _is_ the name of constructors, just like `.cctor` is the name of static initializers.  Why do you think constructors should have an arbitrary name?  In C# it's just the class name, but under the hood its "name" is `.ctor`.

Comment: What makes you think you can "set a method name of a constructor"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [ECMA-335](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-335/) II.10.5.1, constructors *must* be named `.ctor`.

> An instance constructor initializes an instance of a type, and is called when an instance of a type is created by the `newobj` instruction (see Partition III). An instance constructor shall be an instance (not static or virtual) method, it shall be named `.ctor` [...]

You don't need to name the constructor a specific name in order to call it with reflection. Given a `Type t`, you can call one of its constructors by:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(t, arg1, arg2, ...argn);
```

where `arg1, arg2, ...argn` are the arguments you pass to the constructor.

If you really want a name for your constructor, perhaps because you need two constructors that have the same signature but does different things, you can make it a factory method instead. Make a parameterless constructor Use `DefineMethod` to define a static method that calls that constructor, sets some properties of the created object in some way, and returns it. Then you can give a name to that static method.

Answer (score 1):

In IL, constructors don't have names, because they're not real functions in a very specific way: they don't have a return type. The `.ctor` thing (as well as `.cctor`) is just something to help you visualize what it is at a glance, internally they're special entries in classes.

Comment: If you care, another difference is that you cannot have `async` constructors, and exceptions are to be generally avoided because, again, they aren't functions to interrupt, it's part of the garbage collector's memory allocation and initialization.

Comment: `.ctor` is the actual name of the constructor, it's just never used in practice because you can't call it directly.

Answer (score 0):

`.ctor` is the defined name of all instance constructors, as defined by ECMA-335. Contrary to the other answer, **it is actually the name of the function**. But being that constructors cannot be called directly, only via a `newobj` instruction (`new` in C#) it makes little difference.

[ECMA-335 says](https://22.26%20MethodDef%20:%200x06) *(my bold)*:

> **10.5.1 Instance constructor**
>
> An instance constructor initializes an instance of a type, and is called when an instance of a type is created by the `newobj` instruction (see Partition III). An instance constructor shall be an `instance` (not `static` or `virtual`) method, **it shall be named `.ctor`**, and marked `instance`, `rtspecialname`, and `specialname`...

It is also clear from section 22.26, that the actual name `.ctor` is encoded in the executable.